# TypeScript error when dynamically setting color for `chalk` package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, chalk

The [chalk package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) is very popular for terminal styles in Node.

I'm using TypeScript. I'm trying to set the color dynamically. But I am getting a TS error on compile.

Code:

```js
import chalk, { Chalk } from 'chalk';

function getColor(): keyof Chalk {
  let color: keyof Chalk = 'green';

  color = 'yellow';

  return color;
}

const chalkColor = getColor();

// Error on `chalk[chalkColor]`
console.log(chalk[chalkColor]('message'));
```

Error (on `chalk[chalkColor]`):

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'boolean | (Chalk & { supportsColor: ColorSupport; }) | (ChalkConstructor & Function) | Level | ((r: number, g: number, b: number) => Chalk & { supportsColor: ColorSupport; }) | ... 10 more ... | ((color: string) => Chalk & { ...; })' are callable.
    Type 'false' has no call signatures.
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: As it's telling you, not every key into a Chalk gives you back something callable. If you know you're only going to use a color, you could use `as Chalk` to inform the compiler.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you mean `chalk[chalkColor as Chalk]`? Because that gives me an error, so then I do `chalk[(chalkColor as unknown) as Chalk]`, which gives the error: `Type 'Chalk' cannot be used as an index type.`.

Comment: No, the *result* of the indexing, none of the *keys* are Chalk: `(chalk[chalkColor] as Chalk)`.

Comment: Oh thanks, that worked too. `keyof Chalk` is needed on the `color` in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured this out soon after. But I'll leave this question up, just in case someone has a better solution. I used an enum containing the colors I intended to use. That seemed to fix the issue.

```js
import chalk from 'chalk';

enum ChalkColor {
  Green = 'green',
  Yellow = 'yellow',
}

function getColor(): ChalkColor {
  let color = ChalkColor.Green;

  color = ChalkColor.Yellow;

  return color;
}

const chalkColor = getColor();

console.log(chalk[chalkColor]('message'));
```

---

The other solution is to use `(chalk[chalkColor] as Chalk)`, like so:

```js
import chalk, { Chalk } from 'chalk';

function getColor(): keyof Chalk {
  let color: keyof Chalk = 'green';

  color = 'yellow';

  return color;
}

const chalkColor = getColor();

console.log((chalk[chalkColor] as Chalk)('message'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it looks like Chalk makes it even easier that that currently.

https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/chalk

`console.log( chalk.keyword(<colorVariableName>)(TextYouWantToLogOut) )`